# msg.sender.balance showing incorrect amount

Tags: solidity, remix, ether, contract-invocation, ropsten

I've written a smart contract that should return the balance of the current user using it and for some reason when I call the function it's returning the incorrect amount. I've used Remix and the Ropsten network for development/testing this.

```
  function getBalance() public view returns (uint){
    return msg.sender.balance;
  }
```

I am seeing `115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457581007913129639935` as the result even though I have 0.35 ETH in my Ropsten wallet

Anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: Attach all of the code so we can inspect.

Comment: Side note: you don't need a contract for that. For example, using web3.js, you can get the balance of an account via `web3.eth.getBalance(account)`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in `geth` that was resolved in [v1.9.13](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases/tag/v1.9.13).

The original issue can be found in [Issue #16999](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/16999) and the fix can be found in [PR #20783](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/20783).

The issue was basically that `geth` was subtracting `0` by `(gasLimit * gasPrice)`, which underflowed and resulted in the large number you saw. In your case, you were probably using the default Remix values of `gasPrice = 1000000000` and `gasLimit = 3000000`. If you take `0 - (1000000000 * 3000000)`, the resulting value will be the number you posted.

The reason you are seeing it on Remix is because you are probably using MetaMask. MetaMask uses Infura and Infura's nodes are on Geth v1.9.9. You can verify it with the following `curl` command:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"web3_clientVersion","params":[],"id":67}' https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/<project_id>
```